# How to bind CloudStorageAccount input to Azure Function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

### My simplified code sample

I have the following simplified Azure Function code built in Visual Studio 2017:

```
public static class FunctionApp
{
    [FunctionName("MyFunction")]
    public static void Run(
        [TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer,
        [StorageAccount("ConnectionString")] CloudStorageAccount storage)
    {}
}
```

### With the following connection string

I have already added a key "**AzureWebJobsConnectionString**" to the file local.settings.json for development test purpose. However I'm getting the following error message when debugging:

> Error indexing method 'FunctionApp.Run' Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host:
>   Error indexing method 'FunctionApp.Run'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host:
>   Invalid storage account ''. Please make sure your credentials are
>   correct.

The added connection string form is as following:

> BlobEndpoint=https://******.blob.core.windows.net;SharedAccessSignature=sv=2017-04-17&ss=b&srt=sco&sp=dl&se=2099-12-31T00:00:00Z&st=2017-10-22T00:00:00Z&spr=https&sig=******

### And also tested in Azure

Then I configured a connection string named "AzureWebJobsConnectionString" in the Azure Function Portal's Application Settings to test it in Azure, but no success story.

### But still without success :(

How do I get the CloudStorageAccount to properly bind to the Azure Function?

Comment: Could you add your connection string to the question (obfuscate the secrets)?

Comment: @Mikhail added connection string

Comment: @Amry  Go to the azure portal storage/Settings/Access_keys to take a Connection String. The format is   DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<youraccountname>;AccountKey=<youraccountkey>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net

Comment: @RomanKiss FYI, the connection string I used is working fine if I were to do `new CloudStorageAccount(thatConnectionString)`. But I guess now that it has come to this point, I might as well try the account key format.

Comment: @Amry Also, have a look at this https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs/StorageAccountAttribute.cs

Comment: @RomanKiss Already followed the convention as per specified in that source code. And the account key format actually works. It seems that the Azure Functions host is validating the connection string and did not accept the SAS connection string format. Please repost your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the azure portal *storage/Settings/Access_keys* to take a Connection String.

The format is

`DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<youraccountname>‌​;AccountKey=<youracc‌​ountkey>;EndpointSuf‌​fix=core.windows.net`

Comment: The first issue with SAS connection string I faced was an index out of range exception, apparently due to I didn't encode the ampersand (&) character in the SAS to &amp;

After encoding that, I got a proper error message about some validation error. From that I know that Azure Functions host is rejecting the SAS connection string. 

I was thinking of using the SAS connection string for the "limited attack surface" security reason. Oh well..