# How to bind Azure function input parameter to storage account?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-functions

I'm trying to create an Azure Function (.NET core) to retrieve a SaS from a storage account and am struggling to understand why I cannot access the storage.

The function signature:

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run( [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
[StorageAccount("StorageConnectionString")] StorageAccount storage,
ILogger log)
```

When running it, there's this error:

> Error indexing method 'GetBlobSaS' Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host:
>   Cannot bind parameter 'storage' to type StorageAccount. Make sure the
>   parameter Type is supported by the binding. If you're using binding
>   extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure
>   you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your
>   startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(),
>   builder.AddTimers(), etc.).

If I'm creating the storage account reference directly it works fine:

```
var storage = StorageAccount.NewFromConnectionString(System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("StorageConnectionString"));
```

What am I misunderstanding or doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error that you are getting is an error that the Function runtime does not understand the method-signature.
The [StorageAccount] attribute is requiring a CloudStorageAccount.

So change the signature to:

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
    [StorageAccount("StorageConnectionString")] CloudStorageAccount storage,
    ILogger log)
{
```

Comment: No, that's not a custom attribute. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#trigger---attributes and https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs/StorageAccountAttribute.cs

Comment: Ok, but looks like you added it as a Binding attribute. And it's not intended as a binding but as a way to specify which storage account to use when using one of the storage bindings, like QueueTrigger or the Table binding.

Comment: Maybe I misinterpreted the docs. You're saying I can use a blob as an input binding but not get a direct storage reference?

Comment: Not sure, maybe i misinterpreted. According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46879065/how-to-bind-cloudstorageaccount-input-to-azure-function it should work. Maybe you should change it to [StorageAccount("StorageConnectionString")] CloudStorageAccount storage?

Comment: Rock'n roll! That was it! Update you answer, quick! :-)